# Javascript to Typescript Migration: how to export types

Tags: javascript, typescript, dojo, migration

Actually I'm searching for a strategy to migrate our dojo 1.x projects from `javascript` to `typescript`.
My idea was to do it step by step. So in the first step to rename all the `.js` files to `.ts`.
by doing this minimal changes are needed to get a working typescript "class".

example: my class "RequestManager" was defined with declare

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/request/xhr",
  "dojo/_base/connect"
], function (
  declare,
  arr,
  lang,
  xhr,
  connect) {

    return declare("RequestManager", null, {

        _runningRequests: [],
        silentExceptions: false,

        constructor: function () {
            this._runningRequests = [];
        },
```

I changed it to typescript this way:

```js
import declare = require("dojo/_base/declare");
import lang = require("dojo/_base/lang");
import arr = require("dojo/_base/array");
import xhr = require("dojo/request/xhr");
import connect = require("dojo/_base/connect");

export default declare("RequestManager", null, {

    _runningRequests: [],
    silentExceptions: false,

    constructor: function () {
        this._runningRequests = [];
    },
```

But if I want to use it as a type in my `main.ts` it says "**Cannot find Name RequestManager**":

[image: Cannot find Name RequestManager]

But if I create a new Instance the definitions for the functions of this class are visible:

[image: direct instance]

What can I do to get a Type here without changing to a "real typescript-class"? I know if I rewrite everything it will work. But for the first migration step this is too much.

Regards,
wuhi

Comment: I do not know `dojo` but in `typescript ` you usually exports the class, you are exporting the return of `declare` and it does not have any `class` definition

Comment: hmm well i expected such an answer.
so maybe its better to keep the dojo-javascript-classes in javascript-files and create d.ts files for the typings?

Comment: You could try create a `type` definition or interface for `RequestManager` and use it instead.

Comment: well i see. thanks for your comments.
if i keep my old javascript-classes i have to create inferfaces for them.
thats ok and it will help for further migration